# Serial characters are corrupted

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I try to send an "a" string via serial with

```
Serial.println("a");
```

and I receive "Oy=" in Ascii or {4F}{79}{3D} in Hexa.

Where should I start investigating? What could be wrong?  Baudrate is 9600 on all sides.

PS: I suspect the cable. Any hints how to check it?

Comment: It sounds like wrong baud rate. If you set them both the same then maybe the Arduino is running at the wrong speed.

Answer (score 1):

On your setup function

```
Serial.begin(115200);//<- 115200 is the baud rate, serial monitor must match this speed
while(!Serial);//<-- wait for Serial to be ready
```

see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/what-standard-uart-rates-are-there for more baud rates